# Notifications for badges on other Stack Exchange sites use the wrong badge icon

Tags: bug, badges, notifications

Minor bug, but if you get a notification for a new badge the icon used for the badge will be the one for the site you are currently on, not the one where the badge was earned.

[image]

The cause of this is the site-wide standardized css file, which means dynamically resolving the badge for each site might be a little complicated and possibly not worth the effort.

Comment: As you already noticed, the badge style is the style specified in the css of the current site you're browsing. So it'd be complicated and resource-intensive to get the whole css from another sites just to display the badges with the stylings of the site the badges were earned on.

Comment: Agreed, Ill edit that into my post

Comment: But "possibly not worth the effort" is contradicting with the fact you want it to be fixed :P

Comment: @nicael No, I still want it fixed, but I'm being practical and looking at it from a dev's perspective and realizing it's probably not a top of the list issue.